# Distutils can't find gcc from mingwpy in WinPython

Tags: python, mingw, distutils

I'm trying out WinPython as an option to recommend to users who need to run my Python software. Crucially, distutils needs to work with MinGW.

WinPython includes `mingwpy` and provides a `gcc.exe` in the Python scripts directory. When checking `os.environ` I can see that this directory is added to the (temporary) path environment variable.

Unfortunately, distutils still can't find gcc. Does anyone know if there is a way to make distutils find the included gcc file without making changes to the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. If you run the python.exe included with winpython it doesn't set the environment variables and so won't find gcc. If you run the special WinPython.exe it will set the variables and everything works fine.